# why In Windows8 JavaScript append function is not allowed directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a Cordova based Application. Which works perfectly on IOS and android platform. When I am building the Same Application for windows8.It crashes on **append** function.

```
   $("#mainDiv").append(LoginTemplate);
```

I want to maintain the same code base for all platform . Is there any way we can allow the same on windows8 without adding this function everywhere?

```
 MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {

  $("#mainDiv").append(LoginTemplate);

});
```

Is there any way we can put this in config file? So that **append** function will allowed for windows8.  The reason why I want to use this beacause I don't want to maintain a different code base for windows8 just for this.

Comment: `("#mainDiv")` should be `$("#mainDiv")`. Is this only here or also in the actual script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has released a shim that should solve your problem:
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat

It basically wraps all the "unsafe" operations in a `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalfunction` for you automatically.

Comment: Its defintly solved my problm,but it is disabling my popover. Any idea how can enable this popover alone?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. What popover are you using?

Comment: $('[rel=itemspopover]').popover({
    html:true,
    placement:'top',
    content:function(){
        return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
    }
});